# Wait for FileReader - Procedural Javascript

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have a script that parses file data. It starts by using a `FileReader` to get an array buffer, which it then views through various `DataView`s and `Uint8Array`s, and then does a whole bunch of other stuff with the data. I obviously need to wait for the `FileReader` to fire onload before I can move forward with the rest of the code, and I don't really like having to put a massive chunk of code inside a `reader.onload = function() {}` block. Is there a way to make a `FileReader` behave procedurally and just simply hold up the script while it loads?

Comment: Nope. Not that I've heard of. Why would you want this tho? Callbacks are a great feature of JS.

Comment: Its just for clear usage purposes. I just have long procedure that needs to be executed after the load, and it would simply make more sense to use a procedural version. Technically there is no issue. I was mostly curious if I could clean up the code a bit.

Comment: I think long callback functions look fine, tho you might consider removing an indentation :P I just see no purpose for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving this script to a web worker, and discovered `FileReaderSync`, which is EXACTLY what I was after. `FileReaderSync` only works with web workers however, but if you are looking for this type of solution your script should probably be running in a web worker anyway.